# How to add route prefix based on logged in user prefix in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have a route of feedback which is accessible to both `users` and `chancellors` prefixes, but the issue is that I want to write it once in `web.php`, now I have to write it multiple times in `users` and `chancellors` prefixes also I have to change the route name which I don't want to do. Is there any way to do this?

When I use it normally out of the `users` and `chancellors` prefixes it is accessible to both, but it lacks the `users` and `chancellors` prefixes. I want to write this route once and when the user logins with the `users` or `chancellors` prefixes such that the `users/report-feedback` or `chancellors/report-feedback`

```
Route::get('/report-feedback', [FeedbackController::class, 'feedbackForm'])->name('feedbackForm.get');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple routes you'll need to define them multiple times. You can use [route groups](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-groups) to put routes together, but pre-define the callback function used as the argument:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\FeedbackController;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router as RoutingEngine;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$routes = function (RoutingEngine $router) {
    $router->get('/report-feedback', [FeedbackController::class, 'feedbackForm'])
        ->name('feedbackForm.get');
};

Route::name("users.")->prefix("users")->group($routes);
Route::name("chancellors.")->prefix("chancellors")->group($routes);
```

So this will create a route for the URL `users/report-feedback` named `users.feedbackForm.get`, and another for the URL `chancellors/report-feedback` named `chancellors.feedbackForm.get`.

Comment: I know the grouping but this not what I am looking for

Comment: i have only one url for both the prefixes so how can i add only this, can you please tell me how to achieve that for both of the prefixes as because you have different routes name which will cause a issue for me i dont want to use separately. There is only a one url so when user will login with `user` prefix the url will be `users/report-feedback` and when `chancellors` then `chancellors/report-feedback` that it is it. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to use the same route name? Using the same route name is highly discourage. When you do `route('feedbackForm.get');`, it will get the last route defined in the `web.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Route::get('{type}/report-feedback', [FeedbackController::class, 'feedbackForm'])
->where('type', 'users|chancellors')
->name('feedbackForm.get');
```